# How can I add two or more text files into one text file with columns?? (under Linux or Windows)

Tags: linux, text, grep, cat

I have 2 text files:

```
[root@srv32 ~]# cat test1.txt 
apple
orange
grapes
banana
cherry

[root@srv32 ~]# cat test2.txt 
carrot
lettuce
garlic
artichoke
lemon
```

I would like to join the two files in different colums so the output looks like this:

```
[root@srv32 ~]# cat testfinal.txt 
apple carrot
orange lettuce
grapes garlic
banana artichoke
cherry lemon
```

Any idea how can I do this?? Thanks

Comment: Are you looking for [pate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paste_(Unix))?

Answer (score 0):

In linux you use command `paste`:

```
paste test1.txt test2.txt > testfinal.txt
```

In windows I think you have to sacrifice a goat or something.